# How is the heap divided up among processes?

Tags: memory-management, process, operating-system, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I understand that each process has their own, separate heap unlike threads (which share a common heap, which thus slows heap memory allocation down as functions like malloc need to use locks for synchronization). However, how does it get decided where, and how much, memory is given to each process, and how is it ensured that this does not conflict with the memory allocated to other processes?

I have not been able to find a definitive answer on this through searching, but if one exists, please provide a link as I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In order to answer the question, you need to understand about virtual memory. In virtual memory, the memory is contiguous as to what user processes can see. The heap is given a very big about of the virtual memory which is limited only by the amount of physical RAM and swap space to back the allocations. In itself the process only sees a contiguous virtual address space. On Linux, the memory allocations are done using the buddy algorithm and the kernel keeps a page struct for every page. The page struct along with the memory map of the process in the task_struct thus allows the Linux kernel to follow what page is free and which isn't.